# Why am I pulling an error? array.push course work

Tags: arrays

Book has page with the ff code to convert Centigrade to Fahrenheit, we've been asked to rewrite/simplify it.

```js
function convertToCentigrade(degFahren)
{
    var degCent;
    degCent = 5/9 * (degFahren - 32);
    return degCent;
}

var degFahren = new Array(212, 32, -459.15);
var degCent = new Array();
var loopCounter;

for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter <= 2; loopCounter++)
{
    degCent[loopCounter] = convertToCentigrade(degFahren[loopCounter]);
}

for (loopCounter = 2; loopCounter >= 0; loopCounter-- )
{
    document.write(“Value “ + loopCounter + “ was “ + 
        degFahren[loopCounter] + “ degrees Fahrenheit”);
    document.write(“ which is “ + degCent[loopCounter] + 
        “ degrees centigrade<br />”);
}
```

My version:

```js
var degFar = [212, 32, -459.15];
var degCent = [];
            
function convert(input) {
    result = (5/9 * (input - 32));            
    return result;
}
            
for (i = 0; j = degFar.length; i <= j; i++) {
    degCent.push(convert(degFar[i]));
    document.write(degCent[i]);
}
```

I pulling an error (obviously), but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show us what the error is?

Comment: what error do you got? what language do you use? your for for statement looks iffy to me, but i dont know the language so i cant be sure

Answer (score 0):

degFar has 3 elements but its index starts at 0.

Your array is like this:

```
[0] 212
[1] 32
[2] -459.15
```

You're trying to push an index [3] that doesn't exists. So modify your loop with this, notice I replaced `i<=j` for `i<j`:

```
for (i = 0; j = degFar.length; i < j; i++) {
    degCent.push(convert(degFar[i]));
    document.write(degCent[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is causing the error. You try to use two variables, 'j' and 'i'. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish by using 'j' (on top of that you never declared 'j' before trying to initialize it to degFar.length).

Keeping with your logic, I would get rid of 'j'-- you don't need it. After removing 'j' and using 'i' it should look something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < degFar.length; i++) {
 degCent.push(convert(degFar[i]));
 document.write(degCent[i] + "<br>");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot. I used the j variable as that was what was taught to me in a previous module. I was wondering why I couldn't just do i <= degree.length as well. I also forgot I had to declare it first. Thanks again!