# Loop counter resetting to -1

Tags: javascript, for-loop, indexof

This is a course project for a simple search counter for the word "Wrox" in a string.

My code:

```
var myString = "Welcome to Wrox books. ";
myString = myString + "The Wrox website is www.wrox.com. ";
mystring = myString + "Visit the Wrox website today. Thanks for buying Wrox. ";

var i = 0;
var wroxCount = 0;

while (i <= myString.length) {
    i = myString.indexOf("Wrox",i); 
    wroxCount++;  
    i++;
}
```

It works fine until `i` decides to reset to `-1` for some reason. It works until it suddenly doesn't. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Because `indexOf` returns `-1` if whatever you're looking for doesn't exist. so once you find the LAST `Wrox` in your string, obviously there's no more Wroxes past that point, and you get -1. so you find wrox #1, #2, ... #n, then you're back to index 0 and scanning the string over and over and over...

Answer (score 0):

[`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns `-1` when the substring you are searching for was not found in the string.

So this is what you should check against in your while condition, instead of `i <= myString.length` because if `i` is positive, the substring was found inside the string, so the index is lower than the length.

```
i = myString.indexOf('Wrox');
while (i > 0) {
    wroxCount++;
    i = myString.indexOf('Wrox', i + 1);
}
```

Comment: @xa3d You’re welcome! Please remember to upvote helpful answers and ultimately [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) that solved your problem to mark your questions as resolved. Both here and on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791009/why-am-i-pulling-an-error-array-push-course-work). Thanks :)